Plotting a line graph in R studio that has an x axis that goes down and then up
I have an assignment at uni to make a line graph of the mean with standard error bars from some data we collected. The experiment measured beats per minute of brine shrimp when changing temperature (some shrimp were starved and some were fed - I've only included the starved data here as I'm going to make a separate graph for the fed shrimp once I figure out how to). We took temperature measurements in increments of 2 degrees Celsius from 20C down to 6C and then back up to 20C. The data is named starved2_0 which includes the temperature, the mean beat per minute and the standard error from the data.
I ideally would like to have a graph where the x-axis reads from 20->6->20 but can't figure out how to do this.
The data
temperature<-c(20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
mean<-c(104.50,113.89,103.16,89.57,82.63,77.95,74.41,71.29,76.10,83.71,86.58,100.40,104.39,130.31,111.00)
se<-c(6.85,6.22,4.10,3.82,4.39,2.85,2.94,3.50,7.56,4.87,4.13,5.36,5.22,9.49,13.38)

Here's what I've tried so far:
I saw online that i could write out my data points like this
x=c(20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
y=c(104.5,113.89,103.16,89.57,82.63,77.95,74.41,71.29,76.1,83.71,86.58,100.4,104.39,130.31,111)

ggplot(data.frame(x=1:length(x),y))+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y))
ggplot(x,y)

This plots my data correctly but the x axis goes from 1->15 as I have 15 observations which isn't what i want. and also theres no standard error bars obviously
I then tried this:
ggplot(starved2_0,aes(x=temp,y=mean))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),width=.1)+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()

I then tried this but this just puts both my values for each temperature together and so isn't what i want

Can you please edit your question to explain what the data starved2_0 is?

Plot the data by time point (as you have done) but use scale_x_continuous to label the points by temperature.  You need to do it this way as you can't plot 10 Celsius (say) in two different positions on the same axis.

@Limey can you please explain more about what you mean by you can't plot 10 Celsius (say) in two different positions on the same axis?

@stefan_aus_hannover In general terms: an axis is a scale.  It has a minimum and a maximum.  Each value between the minimum and the maximum is repsented by a unique position on the scale.  So, in OP's case, 10 cannot have two different positions on the scale.  But OP actually wants to plot time(point) on the x-axis, but label the axis with "the temperature recorded at this time point".  That is perfectly possible and allows the same label to appear more than once, even though each occurence represents a different time.

You could add a row_number to the data and then use that for the x-axis. Then manually change the x-axis tick labels.
starved2_0 |>
      mutate(x=row_number()) |>
      ggplot(aes(x=x, y=mean)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=.1)+
      geom_line() +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:15, labels=temperature)



starved2_0 <- data.frame(temperature = c(20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20),
                         mean = c(104.50,113.89,103.16,89.57,82.63,77.95,74.41,71.29,76.10,83.71,86.58,100.40,104.39,130.31,111.00),
                         se = c(6.85,6.22,4.10,3.82,4.39,2.85,2.94,3.50,7.56,4.87,4.13,5.36,5.22,9.49,13.38))


while it doesn't help your question with getting the axis to change, maybe i can help with the error bars?
your second code looks correct to me, have you tried putting the geom_errorbar() part to the end?
ggplot(data = df,
   aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max),
              width=0.1)

for the getting it to go up and then back down again, i wonder if you can change the type for x from a numeric to a string or something that R won't try to put in an order different to the one you've put it in. it might be a pretty clunky solution, sorry.

The geom_errorbar() can be where the OP has it. Also there are errors in your code. It doesn't work with the data provided. Can you make the ggplot work with the provided data?
